# Derivation Heisenberg Uncertainty

Tags: quantum-mechanics, homework-and-exercises, wavefunction, heisenberg-uncertainty-principle

I know there have been many questions posted regarding the derivation of the Heisenberg Uncertainty. I do not want to derive its general form, but instead I would like to calculate its lower minimum for the example of a gaussian function.

Let assume we have a guassian wave-packet $$\psi(t) = b \exp(-at^2).$$ I choose $b$, so that $$\int_{-\infty}^{\infty} \psi(t) dt = 1,$$ i.e. $b = \sqrt{\frac{a}{\pi}}$.

I understand the Fourier transform of $\psi(t)$ in this case is $$\Psi(f) = \exp(-\frac{\pi^2 f^2}{a}).$$

However, I get

$$\sigma_{t}^2 = \int_{-\infty}^{\infty} t^2 \left| \psi(t) \right|^2 dt + 0 = \frac{1}{2^{5/2} \sqrt{\pi a}}$$

$$\sigma_{f}^2 = \int_{-\infty}^{\infty} f^2 \left| \Psi(f) \right|^2 df + 0 = \frac{a^3}{(2 \pi)^{5/2}}$$

I think this will never allow me to find $\Delta t \times \Delta E = \frac{\hbar}{2}$.

I am not sure where my mistake is.

Comment: I think your confusion is in what exactly the time-energy uncertainty relation is. Perhaps you should see the following short video: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=auLZ2WOKiqE&ab_channel=ProfessorMdoesScience. If you would like I can write an answer.

Comment: Thank you but I think I "understand" both time-energy and space-momentum uncertainty relation. I am just wondering where my calculation error is. Note, I made a first mistake for the normalization since the probability density is abs()^2. This gives me b = (2a/pi)^(1/4).

Comment: Okay, it seems like you are treating $t$ as an operator, which is not how the time energy uncertainty relation works. If that's not what you are doing, then its my mistake.

Comment: It works out if I use the symmetric Fourier transform (with pre-factor (2 pi)^{1/2})...